# How to call google TTS Wavenet voice with python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-cloud-speech

I am using [the TTS library from Google](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/#pricing-summary). My code in Python is almost the same as [their sample code](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries). But I cannot manage to call their service with WaveNet voice enabled (I am aiming to non-english language but which is also shown as WaveNet voice supported). My assumption is that it will be based on this [param.](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/texttospeech/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.texttospeech_v1.types.VoiceSelectionParams.name) But I cannot see its use anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Figure it out:

```
# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='cs-CZ',
    name="cs-CZ-Wavenet-A",
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3,
    pitch=0)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)
```

where the **name param** can be found in the JSON example over [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/). For example in Czech it would be **cs-CZ-Wavenet-A** and **"cs-CZ-Standard-A"**.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices is a good link now